# Is it possible in blender dope sheet?

Tags: graph-editor, dopesheet

[image]

I want to increase or decrease the proportion while keeping the keyframes at regular intervals, but is this function possible on the blender?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: I think there's some discussion, along with some possible (although not ideal) solutions here - https://blenderartists.org/t/scaling-keyframes-in-the-dope-sheet-unexpected-result/609082

Answer (score 1):

Just select the keyframes you want and press S to scale:

[image]